# Test is not supporting the variable of another class

Tags: java, junit, static-variables

I have one class shipmentTest

import com.monotonic.Shipment.project.ProductFixture;

```
public class ShipmentTest  {

    private Shipment shipment = new Shipment();

    @Test
    public void shouldAddItems() throws Exception {
        shipment.add(door); // it is not recognizing door and window objs
        shipment.add(window);

        assertThat(shipment, contains(door, window));
    }
```

door and window I have imported from ProductFixture class

```
public static Product door = new Product("Wooden Door", 35);
    public static Product floorPanel = new Product("Floor Panel", 25);
    public static Product window = new Product("Glass Window", 10);
```

I have made the above objects static so that I can access them directly but in my test class it is not recognizing the variable picked from productFicture class

below is the add method of shipment class

```
private final List<Product> products = new ArrayList<Product>();

    public void add(Product product) {
        products.add(product);
    }
```

Can someone please let me know how I can access the door object in my test class without instantiating productFixture class 
Thank you so much

Comment: That's just an import problem... Do you use any IDE?? With your import, replace `shipment.add(door); ` by `shipment.add(ProductFixture.door); `

Comment: it is Eclipse and I am using an import statement
import com.monotonic.Shipment.project.ProductFixture;

Comment: are these classes are in different projects?

Comment: and I have tried to run the test class with adding all the classes in the same package, but it didn't work test class is not picking up my door and window variable

Comment: @Derick, no all are in same project.

Comment: import problems are automatically solved because they are really basic. Either you must configure properly your IDE because your class ProductFixture is not in the test classpath, either you must learn to use your IDE by letting it fixing that kind of problem for you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need `static` `import` in `ShipmentTest`  class.

Change your import

```
import com.monotonic.Shipment.project.ProductFixture;
```

to

```
import static com.monotonic.Shipment.project.ProductFixture.*;
```

Note that **too much static imports are not good** from code readability and maintainability view.

So instead of static import you could just use `ProductFixture.door, ProductFixture.floorPanel`and`ProductFixture.window` with regular import of `ProductFixture` in `ShipmentTest` class.

Answer (score 1):

You can get the variables like this:

```
ProductFixture.door and ProductFixture.window
```